# Selecting from an Array using a random key

Tags: php, arrays, random

My question is a little bit complicated but I will try to explain it as good as I can.

I have an array let's say:

```
$array(5){
      [1]=>1,
      [2]=>2,
      [3]=>3,
      [4]=>4,
      [5]=>5
   }
```

And I have a randomly generated key, let's say `$rand = 34526147;` The length of the key is always the same.

Now the question is: I want to select keys from the array which are ordered randomly BUT BASED ON THE KEY WE HAVE. I mean when I give the same key it will always return the same order but if I change the key it will return differently ordered array. Thank You.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Could you add some examples?

Comment: You mean to use `$rand` as a seed for a random number generator?

Comment: We have a quiz game in which 2 players are playing with each other online. The questions` order is randomly selected from the database, but both players must have the same order of questions. So a unique key is generated for both players. And when a user side AJAX is calling a PHP file on the server with a specific key the PHP should return the randomly ordered questions list which must be the same for both players.  Thank You.

Comment: Van Campen Not a number generator but order generator for the array.

Comment: @YervandKhalapyan: if this doesn't work out, you may want to save question order as another table. `QuestionOrder (id, questionOrderID, questionId, sequence)` or something of the sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is you want to `shuffle()` the array, but make it consistent for whatever `$rand` value is provided. I also believe PHP uses `rand` (behind the scenes) within `shuffle` which makes it possible to use `srand` (giving a consistent randomized order for the provided key). So, with that said:

```
$rand = 34526247;
srand($rand);
shuffle($array);
```

Because you're always seeding random from that same "key" you should get a consistent (repeatable) shuffle outcome. (At least it did with a [brief test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/73a5a4405e76f77e673b2afccdf1b5822e01674a))

*Note: This means `$rand` must be a numeric value. And, if at any point it isn't, you'd need to convert it to one.*

Comment: @StephanB: i was still under the impression you could override it with `srand` (it just save you from calling it natively yourself when you needed a random number). e.g. every `srand(microtime(true)); rand();` call becomes simply `rand();`

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment so fast, I wanted to double check this after you added the brief test. It seems the PHP sandbox caches the output, when I copy your code to a .php on my devbox with PHP 5.3 it produces different output each time.

Comment: @StephanB: Possibly.. I did try to change the value (got a new shuffle output) then replaced the key with the original and received back the previous ordering. (Though they may MD5 the source code and save the cache--who knows).

Comment: As a follow-up, I tried [ideone](http://ideone.com/sObWMZ) changing the stdin values (which wouldn't affect the code base, but I would *think* would remove any caching) an still got a consistent shuffling. (Though I don't have PHP locally to test)

Comment: Hey @Brad Christie maybe I will sound a little bit inexperienced but I googled the srand() function and couldn't understand what it is doing?

Comment: @YervandKhalapyan: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619627/what-does-seeding-mean

Answer (score 1):

`uksort` allows defining a custom sort based on the keys:

```
uksort($array,function($a,$b){
    global $rand;
    return strpos(''.$rand, ''.$a) - strpos(''.$rand, ''.$b);
});
```

Note that this assumes all keys exist in $rand.

Example state of array:

```
Array ( 
    [3] => 3 
    [4] => 4 
    [5] => 5 
    [2] => 2 
    [1] => 1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate a new value for each question / row in addition to its id. This value needs to change with each new key and look random enough to your players. You can simply multiply the id with the key, then order by the rightmost digits, like this:

```
$key = 1243;
$questions = array(
  195741 => array('foo'),
  168762 => array('bar'),
  984133 => array('baz'),
);

$newquestions = array();
foreach ($questions as $id => $row) {
  // calculate a random looking order depending on $key
  $newquestions[$id * $key % 100] = $row;
}
ksort($newquestions);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [19] => Array
        (
            [0] => baz
        )
    [63] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo
        )
    [66] => Array
        (
            [0] => bar
        )
)
```

Edit: Include actual sorting

Comment: +1 for thinking outside of the box (though I may have to unit test it if I get free time to see how reliable that is (and where collisions may lie). For now I just give you kudos. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, the calculation can be extended easily after the general flow is established. For non-gaming I recommend streaming ciphers or hash chains: Order by id, first item gets position hash(id) and all others get hash(previous hash). Works for me :D

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I read you to mean that you are asking if you can change the order of the Qs to match that given in the rand int.

```
$questions = array(
1=>'one',
2=>'two',
3=>'three',
4=>'four',
5=>'five',
);

$rand = 34526147;
$order = array_unique(str_split($rand));


foreach($order as $ord){
if(array_key_exists($ord, $questions)) {
echo 'Q:  ' . $ord . ' is  ' .$questions[$ord] . PHP_EOL;
}
}
```

Gives:

Q: 3 is three

Q: 4 is four

Q: 5 is five

Q: 2 is two

Q: 1 is one