# why is srand required to be called before generating a random number using rand

Tags: c++, c

calling srand on the lines of `srand(time(NULL));` is required to setup the seed for `rand()` to generate a random number.
My question is what is the need for the seed ?

Comment: ***My question is what is the need for the seed ?*** If you do not seed or seed with a fixed value you will get the same set of random numbers each time you run your application.

Comment: I feel the need... the need... **for seed!** [*](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Top_Gun)

Comment: @MarkRansom and _I feel the need... the need... for s(p)eed !!_

Comment: Do you know [**what** a seed is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915400)?  I suspect that if you knew *what*, you would know *the need*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `rand()` function is a *pseudo-random number generator*, i.e.,

> The rand() function returns a pseudo-random integer in the range 0 to RAND_MAX inclusive

The generation of the pseudo-random number depends on the *seed*. If you don't provide a different value as *seed*, you'll get the *same* random number on  every invocation(s) of your application. That's why, the `srand()` is used to *randomize* the seed itself.

Most common practice : `srand(time(NULL))` [Suitable for single-run evaluations].

> what is the need for the *[explicit]* seed ?

Worthy to mention, from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/srand)

> If no seed value is provided, the rand() function is automatically seeded with a value of 1.

Answer (score 3):

I guess your question is why isn't it seeded automatically with an unpredictable value (like the current time).

Having the random number generator generate the same sequence every time a program starts can be handy for debugging.

Comment: Sir, please correct me if i'm wrong, but isn't it like it __is__ actually seeded automatically with a value `1` [without an explicit seed].

Comment: Yes indeed - it is seeded with a known constant (1).

Answer (score 1):

Random number generation is the result of an iterative process. Each time you call rand the following happens:

```
seed := create_new_seed(seed);
return random_number_from_seed(seed);
```

(Note that `create_new_seed` and `random_number_from_seed` are pure functions, they only use their parameters and do not access any globals).

This means that if the seed is always 0, then the series of values returned by `rand` calls will always be the same. In order to allow for different values, a different seed is used in each run. One thing that changes between runs and can easily be used is the start time of the program.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not add srand(), each time you run your program, rand will generate the same random numbers.