# Why I obtain the same number with Random Run?

Tags: java, math, random

I am following a book and in this code:

```
    Random rand = new Random(47);
    int i, j, k;
    j = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    System.out.println("j : " + j);
    k = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    System.out.println("k : " + k);
```

I have the same number in output of the book, that is:

```
j : 59
k : 56
```

If I use

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

without 47 Random Class produces random number and it's ok, but why if I put inside the number 47 joined with `j = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;` Why I obtain the same output of the book?
Thank you

Comment: The parameter for the constructor is for the [random seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed). For more information, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619627/what-does-seeding-mean).

Comment: because a machine can´t be random. By providing a fixed seed you´re guaranteed to produce the same output over and over. In the background a random number still has to be calculated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html):

> If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers.

You can specify the seed in the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random(long))

> Creates a new random number generator using a single long seed.

See also:
[Pseudorandom number generator - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)

Comment: so, the seed is the boot to achieve identical number in the random number generator.

Comment: @Lost_in_the_code I'm not sure what you mean by "boot", but yes, the seed is what allows you to get the same numbers each time.

Comment: I used 'boot' to mean launch :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at address http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random(long) for documentation of constructor. Basically, the argument you put into constructor is so called "Seed" and is used to generate semi-random numbers. If you have the same seed across more applications, you get same results.

Good practice is to use for example `System.currentTimeMillis()` as argument.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, Random is not truly random but pseudorandom. It means it takes a given seed and uses it to generate a sequence of numbers that looks like random (but is enterely predictable and it repeats if you put the same seed).